# Sitecore commerce promotion condition

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I wanted to add a promotion condition in Sitecore Commerce.

I have created a custom promotion condition using a promotion plugin and deployed it to Authoring web site.
I can not see the custom condition in the Sitecore Commerce business tools when I am adding a promotion condition.

I wanted to see the promotion condition when I add a new condition in the promotions section of the business tools.

Comment: Did you also add the Text for your condition (the one which is visible within the dropdown) in commerce terms in content editor?

Comment: @eric gonzalez,  Could you please provide code for you custom promotion condition?  Few things that you may also need to check: 1. you've registered correctly your plugin with a custom condition. You should have something like this: services.Sitecore().Rules(config => config.Registry(registry => registry.RegisterAssembly(assembly))); in your ConfigureSitecore class. 2. your custom plugin is referenced by Sitecore.Commerce.Engine project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating custom promotion, Make sure you follow the steps below.

1. Run dotnet.exe to generate the commerce engine site files and publish the output files 
   to output folder
2. Copy all the files except wwwroot folder and place them in “C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9”.May need to do an IIS reset if it says “file is open”.
3. Navigate to Sitecore path – ‘/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/BusinessTools/Conditions’ and add the condition with ‘Commerce term template’

More details and steps on how to create custom sitecore commerce promotion is avaialable in blog https://horizontalintegration.blog/2018/10/09/sitecore-9-commerce-custom-promotion-condition/